# Binding the enabled bit of a check box

Tags: nsuserdefaults, cocoa-bindings

I have a preferences pane built using Cocoa bindings, and many of the options are check boxes. Some of these should only be editable if others are turned on. Here is an example - the indented (selected) box should only be enabled when the one above it is turned on:

[image]

To make this work I created two entries in my defaults, one for the value of each check box (the first two):

[image]

Testing this worked fine, I could turn the boxes on and off and the values were saved run-to-run as I expected. Ok, finally I want to link the enabled status of the second to the first:

[image]

And at that point, the entire system stops working - the preferences pane opens but it's empty. This prints in the output:

```
2016-02-25 08:46:04.691 SwiftNEC[49564:4153826] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): Cannot create BOOL from object <_NSControllerObjectProxy: 0x618000003be0> of class _NSControllerObjectProxy
```

Un-binding this makes everything work again. Now unless I'm mistaken, the enabled value should be a Boolean, and the preferences definitely is a Boolean (as you can see). Can anyone offer an explanation of how to do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to bind to an NSNumber.  An boolean doesn't have the KVC stuff to notify those controls bound to it that it has changed.  I say "pretty sure" because I'm not sure if that boolean in the plist GUI isn't actually an NSNumber, though.

Comment: That I know: the value *is* actually stored as an NSNumber. But maybe that's the key... do I need to use some sort of transform to turn that NSNumber into a bool? Can I do that in the key path?

Comment: This should work. I get the error when Model Key Path is empty. Add `-NSBindingDebugLogLevel 1` to “Arguments to be passed at launch”.

Comment: Ok, I rolled everything back a couple of days in Git and started all of this over. The key appears to be that the bindings DO work for the Defaults, but do NOT work for Swift basic types. So *one* of those bindings in my entire app was bound to a Swift Bool, and presto, the entire system just fails. Apple could definitely improve the error reporting here!